# How to prevent script function from running when requiring a file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have a script that I run by calling `node filename`. Im trying to unit test a particular function in this file. The problem is when I require the file like `app = require('../app')` it runs the entire script and I only want to access the exported functions. Is there any way to prevent the script functions from running when the file is being imported?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question of 'can I stop the script from running' to do unit tests is essentially *no*. However, there are a number of options that you might find helpful. The first is to make your node module more modular by taking out the actions that run on require. My suggestion on that is to change it so that it takes an argument:

```
    node filename run
```

When the 'run' argument is present, the regular actions fire. This will let you require in the file, which always runs the script, but without the 'run' it will not execute the actions you don't want. You could even have a 'test' option to run it in test mode. A second option that I think is less helpful is to move the function you want to test into its own file and have that required into the main section. You can then make it available to test separately.

Answer (score -1):

What you basically want is to partially execute the module you require.

So the answer is no unless you patch the code of this module.